# Absolutely convergence of sum of a sequence of complex numbers over an arbitrary set

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, absolute-convergence

I read on notes of a course on differential geometry the following statement but it doesn't seem so clear to me.

Let $I$ be a set and $b: I \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a map, where $b_i=b(i)$, namely we are given a sequence of complex numbers indexed by $I$. Now, suppose that $\sum_ib_i$ is absolutely convergent.

> Therefore, the "series" converges to a certain complex number $b$ and this is characterized by the following property.
> For each $\epsilon >0$ and each finite subset $J \subset I$ there exists a finite subset $J \subset K \subset I$ such that $$|b-\sum_{i \in K }b_i|<\epsilon$$

I would like to know how to prove this characterization for the limit $b$.

Thank you

Comment: How is "absolutely convergent" defined?

Comment: The correct definition: for each $\epsilon> 0$ there exists a finite $J \subset I$ such that for every finite $K$, $J\subset K \subset I$ we have $|b - \sum_{i \in K} b_i| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Is absolutely convergent if the sum of the modules is finite. Therefore, we already know that only many countable numbers are nonzero. 
Furthermore, this one is not a definition, it should be a characterization (in fact is weaker)

Comment: How is this related to differential-geometry?

Comment: I think series are used to make a link between differential geometry and algebraic geometry in these notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c=\sup \sum_{j \in J}|b_j|$ taken on all finite subsets of $I$; by hypothesis $c$ is finite so for all $n \ge 1$ there is $K_n$ finite subset of $I$ st $0 \le c-\sum_{j \in K_n}|b_j| <\frac{1}{n}$ so in particular $\sum_{j \in J -K_n}|b_j| < \frac{1}{n}$ for all finite subsets $J$ of $I$ as otherwise $\sum_{j \in J \cup K_n}|b_j| >c$ contradicting the definition of $c$

But now if $a_n=\sum_{j \in K_n}b_j$ we have that $$|a_n-a_m| = |\sum_{j \in K_n -K_m}b_j-\sum_{j \in K_m -K_n}b_j| \le \sum_{j \in K_m -K_n}|b_j|+\sum_{j \in K_n -K_m}|b_j| \le \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}$$

This means that $a_n$ is Cauchy, hence it has a limit $b$ and for every $J$ finite, we have that $$|\sum_{j \in J \cup K_n}b_j-b| \le |\sum_{j \in K_n}b_j-b|+|\sum_{j \in J-K_n}b_j|\le |a_n-b|+\frac{1}{n}$$ which clearly gives the required result with
$K=J \cup K_n$ and $n$ large enough so $|a_n-b|+\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$

Comment: Thanks, but can I ask clarification about why this is a characterization for $b$?

Comment: For any set $I$ the collection of its finite subsets forms a net under inclusion (net being a partial order st any two elements have a common element that's greater than both of them; partitions of intervals in the theory of Riemann (Riemann Stieltjes) integrals are another example of a commonly used net) and the above reflects that $a_K=\sum_{j \in K}b_j \to b$ in the net sense (same with the fact that Riemann or Darboux sums converge to the Riemann integral in the net sense) since with the same proof one has that $|a_F-b| < \epsilon$ for every finite $K \subset K(J)=J\cup K_n \subset F$

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could I ask for some references on this topic?